# What kind the implementation it is?

Tags: scala, akka, akka-typed

On the [akka website](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/typed/persistence.html), you can the following definition:

```
sealed trait AccountCommand[Reply] extends ExpectingReply[Reply]
final case class Withdraw(amount: BigDecimal)(override val replyTo: ActorRef[OperationResult])
    extends AccountCommand[OperationResult]
```

How to assign an `ActorRef` to `replyTo`?

I've taken the code as an example and try to implement on own type:

```
case object Channel (override val replyTo: ActorRef[SendMessage])
  extends ExpectingReply[SendMessage]
```

and the compiler complains.

The way, that the compiler does not complain:

```
case object Channel extends ExpectingReply[SendMessage] {
  override def replyTo: ActorRef[SendMessage] = ???
}
```

Is the example on akka website wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your message does not have fields, you can use a `case class` without parameters:

```scala
case class Channel()(override val replyTo: ActorRef[SendMessage])
  extends ExpectingReply[SendMessage]
```

If you're asking about how to create an instance of such a class, then you should use the standard multi-parameter function call syntax:

```scala
val msg = Channel()(sendMessageActorRef)
```

That being said, it looks to me that specifically in that part of the Akka API that you linked to, you don't have to explicitly provide any `ActorRef`s, `Effect`s seem to do it kind of automatically.